# Getting value from <h4> in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Child

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class Card extends Component {

render() {

let props = this.props;

return(
        <div className="card-main">
            <img src={`http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/${props.path}`} alt="Poster" />
            <div className="card-deatils">
                <h4 className="card-name">{props.name}</h4>
                <h4 className="id card-name">{props.id}</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
);
}
}

export default Card;
```

I want to get the id stored in  with class "id". The problem is that from previous component the amount cards are at minimum 20 in the page and what I ideally want is to pass id back to its parent component. Most of the methods I tried give value undefined.

Parent

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import Card from './Card'

class CardArray extends Component {

render() {

    var props = this.props

    return (
        <div className="pop-movie-container">
        <div className="card">
                    {
                        props.popNames.map((val,index) => {
                            return(
                            <Card
                            key ={props.popId[index]}
                            id={props.popId[index]}
                            name={props.popNames[index]} 
                            path={props.popPath[index]}
                            />
                            );
                        })
                    }
        </div>
        <div className="load-more">
            <button className="btn btn-12" onClick={props.change}>LOAD MORE</button>
        </div>
        </div>  
    );

}

}

export default CardArray;
```

popNames is an array containing 20 names at minimum and increases by 20 on click of load more.

So, ideally what I want is that to get id from Card passed to CardArray.

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NQcx.jpg)

So, when someone clicks on card more information can be fetched from the api using id of movie

Comment: Probably you don't need to pass the ID to the parent component, because the `CardArray` already has the `props.popId[index]` when generating the child.
What will you use the id for?

Comment: I think you already have id passed to card component. props.id . ANd this is the id which you need to make the api call ?

Comment: How can I know which of the card has been clicked. When a user clicks on the card Popular Movies section will be replaced by the details of the movie clicked and to get these details I need id of the movie to fetch data from API. API aceepts the movie id and gives relevant info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

parent

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Card from "./Card";

class CardArray extends Component {
  fetchDetails = (id) => {
    // fetching logic goes here
  }
  render() {
    var props = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="pop-movie-container">
        <div className="card">
          {props.popNames.map((val, index) => {
            return (
              <Card
                key={props.popId[index]}
                id={props.popId[index]}
                name={props.popNames[index]}
                path={props.popPath[index]}
                handelClick={this.fetchDetails}
              />
            );
          })}
        </div>
        <div className="load-more">
          <button className="btn btn-12" onClick={props.change}>
            LOAD MORE
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CardArray;
```

child

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Card extends Component {
  render() {
    let props = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="card-main" onClick={() => this.props.handelClick(this.props.id)}>
        <img
          src={`http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/${props.path}`}
          alt="Poster"
        />
        <div className="card-deatils">
          <h4 className="card-name">{props.name}</h4>
          <h4 className="id card-name">{props.id}</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Card;
```

u can pass an function as props to child and child can call that function with id.
if you need more explanation let me know.

also once quick suggestion you can directly pass

`name={val}` instead of `name={props.popNames[index]}`

Comment: Good answer, another thing to note for other learners is the reason for this pattern in react. React uses a component life cycle which is broken down into different phases to help keep track of when to do what next. In this way it knows when to render and when not to. As a stipulation to make this work you cannot fire state changing methods in the render/return unless you are in an event handler. or at least it is highly suggested not to.